# Why Do Van De Graaff Generators Only Shock When Grounding Someone?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-current, charge

When someone touchs the metal sphere of the Van De Graaff Generators, the charge on them builds up, causing the famous hair raising. However, why is it when a person is rapidly grounded by someone help holding metal, does a sudden shock occur? Is it due to all of the charges taken the path of least resistance, causing a higher perceived current?

Comment: https://energized.edison.com/stories/why-can-birds-sit-safely-on-power-lines

Answer (score 0):

when you put your hand on the charge collection sphere of the generator and then it is turned on, the stored charge builds up relatively slowly and has time to distribute itself uniformly over your body so the voltage *difference* between, say, your right hand (on the sphere) and your left (not touching anything) is very tiny even though the charge stored on the surface of your body  and the sphere is significant.

If you then grab a grounded metal rod with your left hand, your left hand is clamped at 0 volts while your right hand is still at the same voltage as the sphere (tens of thousands of volts). The voltage *difference* is huge and it then drives the flow of current from one hand to the other. That current then passes through your chest, stops your heartbeat, and you die.